# What is the best way to get a huge amount of content to your website?

Tags: content, writing

I have been working on 2 websites for a long time and the most challenging work is to create good content. I write the articles myself and sometimes hire an external service to do it for me (around 7-10 uds each and poor quality).
At this moment my site has around 400 pages indexed, all of them created by me and taking me a lot of time.

I've noticed that some of my competitors have 6.000, 12.000 pages (not forums, etc, but proper articles and samples) and they are individual webmasters like me.

How is possible to have this huge amount of pages/content working alone and with a small budget?

Basically, I need to improve my site with templates, samples, like job description templates, resume templates, etc. My competitors have tons of them duly written and formated.

Can you please help me suggesting some good/alternatives source to create web content, preferible for free or maximum for 1usd-3usd price each?

Comment: There's no need to shout.

Comment: Sorry, danlefree. It was not my intention. Just to highlight what was my real question.

Comment: I would  suggest looking at WordPress's site architecture. And then I would recommend looking into parsing files from other websites I assume it has something to do with jobs so for example like indeed horses and pulls their jobs from a bunch of different websites.  I own a video site and it forces and scrapes videos from other sites and then we change the description and change the title to make it unique to us. We're not taking anyone's content this is videos that you see all over the internet. This is talk to text so I apologize for the grammatical errors.

Answer (score 17):

How about this: don't create a website if you don't have anything (meaningful) to put on it.

I know, it's crazy. But sometimes it's best to wait until you have something of value to contribute before you start throwing up websites and trying to get them indexed by search engines.

Most successful websites are successful because their creators came up with a really good idea for an application/service, or they have a lot of useful knowledge or other interesting content to share with others. You don't just decide one day "hey, I'm gonna create a website and make money from advertising!" and then start building and promoting it before you come up with a source of useful content. People who do that are generally spammers. Their only motivation is to make a quick buck despite having nothing to contribute to the online community, so they create spam blogs or other equally useless sites with low quality content and load them up with ads. And then they have to go around comment-spamming on other people's blogs because their low quality content isn't generating any natural backlinks.

People who own successful/quality content-based sites have all slowly built their site up over time. They don't just start with 6000 pages of content. A blog author starts with just one blog post, and over many years of posting regularly, they slowly build up a significant pool of content as well as followers. Usually they start the blog just for the fun of it, because they're passionate about a particular field or topic. And then by chance they discover that they're good writers and that people are actually interested in what they have to say. And it's only then that they turn their hobby into a business and start monetizing their site by including a reasonable amount of advertising.

But those individuals are in the minority. Most people just aren't able to create compelling content that they could actually make money off of, much less create such content in bulk. Even professional bloggers are only able to write when inspiration strikes, or when they have something to write about. Good writing takes time. That's why hiring a copywriter to deliver 50 articles in a month will get you very low quality content. That's also why most sites that publish a lot of content regularly have a full-time writing staff of 10-20 or more writers.

If you want to pay $7~$8 per article/template/whatever, then how good do you expect it to be? A good article takes at least a couple of hours to write, if not a couple of days. And a good author isn't going to work for $1/hr.

If you don't have the money to pay for professional writers, then you'll need to write it yourself. But then you have to first ask yourself whether you're qualified to write on the subject of your site: Are you a good writer (or at least a competent one)? Are you an expert on the topic you're writing about? I.e. Were you formally trained in it in school? Do you have industry experience? Do you actually have any insights on the topic or are you just writing because you need more content for SEO purposes?

By the sound of your question, it doesn't seem like you should be running a website, much less 2 websites. This quantity over quality approach is characteristic of spam blogs, and the web doesn't need any more of those. A legitimate site should be focused on generating moderate amounts of quality content, not trying to generate bulk content to meet some kind of quota. Instead of flooding search indexes with hundreds or thousands of low quality pages, you should just figure out a way to write small amounts of original, high quality content that people will link to, thus giving them high search ranking. That will get you more visitors, and they'll be repeat visitors too.

Comment: `hey, I'm gonna create a website and make money from advertising!` - oh but so many people do say that! (and 99.9% of them fail)

Comment: +1 Couldn't answer better. Congrats Lèse majesté

Comment: Thanks, Lèse majesté. 
Writing small amounts of original, high quality content that people will link to, thus giving them high search ranking was my way until now. Just trying to figure out how to speed up this process as my perception is that my competence, in somehow, is being able to do it.

Comment: @Adriana: This is a really late reply, but I think this is the reason why a lot of web zines are started by teams of writers. If you can find a couple of friends or some kindred spirits, you might enlist their help in generating content. This is also beneficial as you have people to edit/proofread and give feedback on your writing, and writing as a team improves morale and motivation.

Comment: Perhaps the fact you aren't even using words like "competence" correctly may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

Look at StackExchange and Wikipedia : for me, the best way to get a huge amout of quality content is the collaborative way.

You "just" have to provide strong infrastructure (good ergonomic/moderation/scalability...)

Comment: If people want wikipedia's articles or StackExchange information they'll just go to those websites. Not to mention duplicate content really doesn't benefit anyone.

Comment: @John I think that G.Qyy wanted to give stackexchange and wikipedia as examples to the mantra of "Let the users create your content".

Comment: I don't think that's what they were saying. There's a big difference between user created content and taking freely available content from other websites.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to give this site as examples to say "if you want lot of content, provide a good infrastructure, and let the user fill your website", I *never* want to say "copy past content from other site"!

Answer (score 3):

If you have programming skills organize freely available content in a useful way. To use an obvious example Google.com contains no unique content of their own, but is great at organizing content so they get tons of content for free (in fact people fall all over themselves to give Google data). I'm not sure what industry you're in but based your question including job resumes etc. I suspect you might find some of the census data useful or see what resources the SBA has to offer. Here are a few available data sets for example.

http://factfinder.census.gov/servlet/DatasetMainPageServlet
http://www.google.com/publicdata/directory

Comment: Google is a service provider. Their service is search, webmail, cloud hosting, advertising, online document management/editing, etc. That is their unique "content". All of their successful services are successful because they provides an excellent user experience and are always innovating in the industries they're involved in. But they're still relying primarily on their own unique content--an industry-leading search index. It's not the page snippets on SERPs that bring people to Google. It's Google's ranking data that they generate using intensive data analysis.

Comment: Exactly my point, they use the web content you created and organize it for search, they organize your emails that you created for gmail they organize and secure the files you created and host in the cloud and so on. They are not useful because they have their own content they are useful because of what they do with the content you give them.

Comment: Thanks, Joshak. Interesting data in the link above. Sure I will use some of them to help me on my content creation from now on.